# Capacitors for high current systems?

Tags: power-supply, capacitor, current, capacitance, heat

Why area capacitors considered ideal for systems that require excessively high current(in the magnitude \$ 10^6 \$) for short pulses? Also, how can they manage to output high current in that range without causing severe damage? High current at that magnitude would lead to massive heat. I can't imagine the system to function more that a few ms, is a second or more even possible?!

How can they manage the capacitors energy storing capacity & how they are connected(series/parallel), with respect to the resistance of all the wires & terminals connecting everything, Incredible systems.

Comment: You said it yourself: "short pulses". You can consume a large amount of power for a short time and only cause a temperature increase proportional to \$Pt\$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A one second pulse of \$ 10^6 \$ amps through a resistance of 0.01 ohms would dissipate \$ 10^{10} \$ joules of energy. That is equivalent to about 2.4 tons of TNT. A one ms pulse in the same resistance would dissipate \$ 10^7 \$ joules of energy. That is equivalent to about 10 sticks of dynamite.

Any high current pulse system must use capacitors with very low internal resistance and very low resistance conductors. In addition, the magnetic fields produced will cause significant mechanical forces on the conductors. In a laboratory, have seen fault currents much lower than that cause heavy cables on the floor to move like snakes.